# Dictionary word count

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

So I am trying to get this program to count all the words and the number of times each word is used and put it in a dictionary with a count. It seems to be counting the words correctly but I can't get it to print the correct word with the count.

```
import urllib.request
words_to_count={}
url='http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/Classes/15F/cis122/data/alice1.txt'
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as webpage:
    for line in webpage:
        line=line.strip()
        line=line.decode('utf-8')
        line=line.lower()
        if len(line)>0:
            line_list=line.split(" ")
        for word in line_list:
            if word in words_to_count:
                words_to_count[word
                           ]+=1
            else:
                words_to_count[word]=1
for words in sorted(words_to_count):
    count=words_to_count [words]
    show_word=format(word,'<12s')
    show_count=format( count,'6d')
    print(show_word, show_count)
```

Comment: What is your current output and what is the expected one? This platform does not debug your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of this line:

```
show_word=format(word,'<12s')
```

You are using `word`, but you should have using `words` as introduced in the for-loop.

`word` is a variable from your previous for-loop.